# How do I get this LCD to work on Proteus?

Tags: digital-logic, lcd, proteus, hd44780

I'm trying to display the letter "A" on LM016L ([datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/305035.pdf)). I keep switching the E input but I get nothing.

This is my circuit:
[image: datasheet]

Comment: So, all we can tell you is that this isn't working. Explain what debugging this far has revealed. You say you switch the "E" input, but that's just "enable". How do you know things should be displayed? What should happen? Does the device at least draw the expected supply current? We'll need more hints at what might be going wrong. Alos, remove the [tag:arduino] and [tag:fpga] tags. You refer to neither in your question, and "hey, there's probably clever people looking out for this tag" is a **very** discouraged reason to use a tag.

Comment: @MarcusMüller According to the datasheet I linked, the supplies that I have provided should be right. Or I'm getting it wrong. And the data I have specified to D0...D7 should be displayed when E changes. I have been looking this up for a few hours now and haven't found something that points to my mistake. So, I'd really appreciate it if you could suggest something I can try.

Comment: @MarcusMüller About the tags, this is part of a project that involves FPGA and when I looked LCD up on the internet, almost all the guides I saw involved Arduino. So I figured maybe I need those to get it to work. Forgive me if this is a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to display the letter "A" on LM016L. I keep switching the E input but I get nothing.

Your current plan will not work.

Although your linked LCD module datasheet appears to be an abbreviated version, it says this LCD module uses the [HD44780 controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_HD44780_LCD_controller). That is what you need to research.

For example, although *not* all LCD modules which claim to use [HD44780](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf) commands behave exactly the same, they tend to start in a "display off" state, and need to be sent the correct commands before they will even start to show anything. Therefore you need to research HD44780 initialisation.

Comment: @MylaIzaman, I have deleted my answer (which recommended improving 'E' signal quality) as I belatedly realised that the LCD needs initialising. My answer was rubbish and SamGibson is absolutely right so apologies for wasting your time.